# Hide passwordToggleEnable when error warnings occur

Tags: android, passwords, android-textinputlayout

can we hide passwordToggle temporary when user get warning error and display it back when user fill the EditText with some data, look at this picture

[image: pic 1] and [image: pic 2]

if i tried this

```
if (etPassNow.length() == 0){
    etPassNow.setError("No data");
    textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
}
```

then the result is like this

[image: pic3], but this is what i want [image: pic4] there's an icon error above error warning,

has anyone ever meet this issue? Thank you

This is my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/ti_new_pass"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_new_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Kata Sandi Baru"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/dc_gray"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my conclusion after getting trial error, i'm checking the error if field empty in onClick action

```
if (etPassNow.length() == 0)
     etPassNow.setError("Please fill data");
```

and for passwordToggle i activate it in onTextChange

```
etPassNow.addTextChangeListener(this);

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
     if (etPassNow.getText().toString().length() > 0)
          textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
     else
          textInputLayout.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
}
```

this is the easiest way for my case

Answer (score 3):

The above used method has been deprecated hence no longer used so for this we have to use new Method

```
passwordTxtInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout_password);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        if (etPassword != null) {
            etPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    passwordTxtInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(true);

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

and call this function whenever the password length is less than and equal to zero

```
passwordTxtInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(false);
```

Make sure this function should be called before calling setError otherwise eyeIcon will be disable.

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```js
if (etPassNow.length() == 0) {
            etPassNow.setError("No data");
            etPassNow.setTransformationMethod(null);
        } else {
            etPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        }
```

Comment: that's where else part come  etPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod()); have included this code it will show icon when string length is > 0

Comment: yes i already try it, but its not what i want. I want to implement it in password and there are 2 toggle, 1 for show/hide password and if error detected, toggle 1 is gone and toggle 2 for error message is show. i used **app:passwordToggleEnable="true"** in **TextInputLayout**